# Kotlin compare two Dates

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make input validation on a date that the user add. I want to check if the Date added by the user is after **Today** Date, but I don't understand how to do this.
The date that the user insert is a String so i have to convert it to a Date, but I need to get the today date and compare with the input date.
For now I write this:

```
fun isDateValid(myDate: String) : Boolean{
           val date = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(myDate)
           return //compare 2 the dates
}
```

So i convert the date given by the user to Date type, but how can I get the local Date (now) and compare the two Dates? I am using API 21 so I can't use LocalDateTime because it give me error

**UPDATE**
I trying Lino answer:

```
fun isDateValid(myDate: String) : Boolean{
            val date = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(myDate)
            return !date.before(Date())
}
```

but i get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ticketapp, PID: 9173
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:362)
        at com.example.ticketapp.Util$Companion.isDeadLineValid(Util.kt:32)
        at com.example.ticketapp.ui.newTicket.NewTicketViewModel.checkInputs(NewTicketViewModel.kt:222)
        at com.example.ticketapp.ui.newTicket.NewTicketViewModel.createTicket(NewTicketViewModel.kt:196)
        at com.example.ticketapp.databinding.FragmentNewTicketBindingImpl._internalCallbackOnClick(FragmentNewTicketBindingImpl.java:783)
        at com.example.ticketapp.generated.callback.OnClickListener.onClick(OnClickListener.java:11)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9173 SIG: 9
```

Comment: So how can I do that?

Comment: `return !myDate.before(Date())` not working @Lino

Comment: @Lino when i run the app i get 

`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ticketapp, PID: 9173
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

Comment: @Lino the IDE say `Unsafe use of a nullable receiver of type Date?` on the return line

Comment: @Lino i updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to check if your date is valid:

```kotlin
fun isDateValid(myDate: String) : Boolean {
    try {
        val date = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(myDate)
        return !date.before(Date())
    } catch(ignored: java.text.ParseException) {
        return false
    }
}
```

You can also factor out the `SimpleDateFormat` and put that into a top-level variable in the same file / class as `isDateValid()`:

```kotlin
private val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

then replace:

```kotlin
val date = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(myDate)
```

with

```kotlin
val date = formatter.parse(myDate)
```

Comment: it works! but this exception ignore can cause error in future?

Comment: @androidzzaza99 you can still log that exception

Comment: for now i not get error, but the ignore exception is safe?

Comment: @androidzzaza99 as said earlier, you can still log the error, i.e. using the log4j framework or something like that. It doesn't have to be on ERROR-level, maybe DEBUG is fine, because you expect this exception

Comment: @Lino Why the downvote do you know? it seems correct to me

Comment: @dreamcrash I assume that it's a *too easy* answer, I downvote such questions normally too, so it may aswell be karma or revenge, I don't really know, nor care though.

Comment: @Lino yep, but if you are an outsider searching for an answer and you endup here and you are not aware you might wrongly think that the answer is incorrect

Comment: @dreamcrash agreed, although I don't expect that this question will generate lots of traffic, nor receive more attention than it already has.